# CentOS 8 install containerd.io-1.2.13 rpm package

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

on my CentOs 8 machine, I have configure docker stable repo, also see below package in the repo. But when I list he patch from my system, it shows only `1.2.0`.  Not sure why its not showing the latest version.

How to get the latest package from this repo?

https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm

```
# head /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
[docker-ce-stable]
name=Docker CE Stable - $basearch
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/$basearch/stable
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg
```

**package list**

```
 yum list containerd.io  --showduplicates

Installed Packages
containerd.io.x86_64                                                                  1.2.0-3.el7                                                                            @docker-ce-stable
Available Packages
containerd.io.x86_64                                                                  1.2.0-1.2.beta.2.el7                                                                   docker-ce-stable
containerd.io.x86_64                                                                  1.2.0-2.0.rc.0.1.el7                                                                   docker-ce-stable
containerd.io.x86_64                                                                  1.2.0-2.2.rc.2.1.el7                                                                   docker-ce-stable
containerd.io.x86_64                                                                  1.2.0-3.el7                                                                            docker-ce-stable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `module_hotfixes=1` to the `docker-ce-stable` DNF repository configuration. Note that while this will make Docker work, it will keep you from having a working Podman, so if you ever want to switch, you'd need to undo that change and clean up the packages that got installed as a result.